# Erro ao retornar valores de um dicionário Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lógica

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de agenda, onde o usuário poderá cadastrar até 5 contatos. Depois de muito sofrimento tentando fazer o sistema baseado em listas resolvi optar por dicionário. O usuário tem 3 opções: 1 - Cadastrar, 2 - Mostrar cadastros e 0 - Finalizar.  Consegui fazer boa parte do processo, mas ao acionar a opção 2 não recebo todos os contatos cadastrados, apenas o ultimo. Alguém consegue me dar uma luz de como resolver?
Segue o código:

```
opt = 0
tam = 4
ind = 0
total_agenda=[]
lista_agenda = []
agenda = dict()

while True:
    # Menu de opções
    print("="*31)
    print("1 - Inserir um novo cadastro ")
    print("2 - Mostrar todos os cadastros ")
    print("0 - Encerrar ")
    print("="*31)
    opt = input("Digite a opção desejada:  ")  
    print("="*31)
    # Verificador de entrada inválida
    if(opt!= "0" and opt != "1" and opt!="2"):
        print("Erro: opção inválida!") 
    # Opção 1 - inserir novo cadastro   
    elif opt == "1":
        if(len(total_agenda)>4): # Limitador para apenas 5 cadastros
            print("Agenda lotada!")
        else:
            agenda = dict() # cria uma lista para adicionar o id, nome, telefone e e-mail
            agenda["id"]= ind+1 # Cria um id para cada cadastro
            agenda["nome"] = input("Digite o nome do contato : ")
            agenda["telefone"] = input("Digite o telefone do contato : ")
            agenda["email"] = input("Agora digite o e-mail do contato : ")
            lista_agenda.append(agenda)
            total_agenda.append(lista_agenda) # Adiciona os dados preenchidos na lista agenda na lista total_agenda
    # Opção 2 - mostrar os cadastros 
    elif opt == "2":
        if(len(total_agenda)==0):
          print("Lista vazia!")
        else:
            print ("Os contatos cadastrados foram: ")
            for r in (total_agenda):
                for k, v in agenda.items():
                    print(f"{k} : {v}")
                    
    #Opção 3 - Encerrar sistema
    elif opt == "0":
        break

print("Sistema encerrado!")
```

[Cadastrei 2 contatos: NOME1 e NOME2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nn6j.jpg)
[Mas ao retornar os contatos cadastrados só aparece o ultimo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4UGW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em resumo o problema está no momento em que você chama o dicionário, veja que você está listando os dados da "agenda" variável que vc definiu no inicio do código e não os dicionários que estão dentro da sua lista.

Vamos por parte

Neste ponto você está esquecendo de aumentar o valor de "ind" então todos os seus registros terão id = 1

```
agenda["id"] = ind + 1
```

Neste ponto temos um problema de lógica, você está criando um dicionario e adicionando ele em uma lista e após isso adicionando essa lista dentro de outra lista, pelo menos para o seu proposito não vejo necessidade de adicionar a lista "lista_agenda" na lista "total_agenda"

```
lista_agenda.append(agenda)
total_agenda.append(lista_agenda)
```

Para visualizar melhor o que você está fazendo tente colocar, após você realizar o append.

```
print(lista_agenda)
print(total_agenda)
```

Mas o problema de fato está aqui

```
for r in (total_agenda):
    for k, v in agenda.items():
        print(f"{k} : {v}")
```

Veja que o trecho colocado acima, você não está listando os itens dicionário que está na lista e sim os itens que está no dicionario criado no inicio do codigo, nomeado como agenda e que é o mesmo que você utiliza para guardar os inputs quando opt = 1, e é por isso que você visualiza apenas a ultima agenda quando você printa.

Para resolver a logica do seu codigo, podes remover a existencia da lista "total_agenda" ficando apenas com "lista_agenda" e no trecho do codigo em que você print os dados da agenda quando opt = 2 você ajusta para deixar assim:

```
for r in (lista_agenda):
    for k, v in r.items():
        print(f"{k} : {v}")
```

Dessa forma você estará navegando item por item da lista "lista_agenda" e realizando a exibição de todos as agendas criadas e não apenas a ultima, pois aplicando o "items()" na variavel "r" você está utilizando a variável salva na lista.

Para entender melhor o que está acontecendo, podes revisar sobre Escopo de variáveis e sobre listas.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. Um detalhe tão pequeno faz tanta diferença.